# Tidy up names using regexp in google sheets script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a neat code to standardize names, using google sheet script and regexp.
Each value (all in caps) has a first name composed of 1 or 2 words.
Then comes the second name with just the initial(s). If it is a composed name, there are 2 initials. When there are 2 initials, the formatting varies greatly.

What I want to achieve, using google script : keep the first name full, and standardize the second name as one or two characters followed by a dot.

"LE FARD MA." , "LE FARD M.A." , "LE FARD M-A" , "LE FARD M A." , "LE FARD M. A." , "LE FARD M.-A." , "LE FARD M-A." : should all return "LE FARD MA."

"FARD P". , "FARD P" : should return "FARD P."

I have been trying to learn about regexp for the past few hours, but can't manage to find an answer. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the script you already have written. This is not a program writing service.

Comment: There are plenty of regex testers online. Try figuring it out with [regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of s1c0j1, I managed to get a code working.

```
function Test() {
  var a ="LE FARD M-A.";
  var regex = new RegExp(/(?:\s+)(\w?)(?:\.?\s?-?)(\w?)\.?$/);
  var res = regex(a);
  var haha = a.replace(res[0]," " + res[1] + res[2] + ".");
  Logger.log(haha);
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant way, but problem solved, thanks.